# Dividing 10 acres of land into 100 *100 feet parcels

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have used hand held GPS to determine the acreage of a land. And I have plotted them into QGIS. But I don't know how to divide it into 100*100 parcels of land.

And how to also carve out an 80ft and 40ft road from it using QGIS.

I am aiming to plan the 10 acres of land for habitation.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Create grid tool - Intersect with your data

Comment: To create the road: Digitize a line where the middle should be using a ft-based CRS, then buffer by 40 respectively 80.

Comment: You really ought to to be talking to a licensed professional surveyor. There may be laws which make do-it-yourself survey a crime.